# How to select all attributes under an element using xmlstarlet?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

How to use `xmlstarlet` to get the `hrefs` from the following `div`?

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="my_list">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://mylink1.html" title="title1">this is title 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://mylink2.html" title="title2">this is title 2</a></li>
 ...
 </ul>
</div>
```

I tried the following `xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//*[@class='my_list']" -v "." myfile.xml`on my mac, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append `//@href` to your XPath expression to get all `@href` attributes beneath the nodes it already selects:

```
//*[@class='my_list']//@href
```

**Explanation:**

Your base XPath was fine for selecting the `div` of interest.  It bypasses the need to declare a namespace for `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` by using the element wildcard, `*` and then specifying a value for `@class`, which is not affected by the default namespace declaration on the `div` of interest.

From there, `//` selects along the descendent-or-self axis -- `/` would only select along the immediate child axis -- and `@href` selects the `href` attributes requested.

Comment: Hi, this works on my computer. Before marking as solved, could you please explain briefly the format used? why `//` and not just `@href`??